# Odd structure - 何か　見つけました？

Tags: grammar, politeness

Recently I have been enjoying the show Chii Sanpou. I expect a few of you have seen or heard of it. The former actor walking around parts of Japan. The Japanese is a mix of casual and polite.

Anyway in one episode he spots something and the narrator says

```
何か、　見つけました？
```

which to me is an odd pattern. I think it is "what did you see?". It appears to be polite Japanese but the structure is not what I have been taught. I would have expected

```
何を見つけましたか？
```

I would like to know more about this other form. Is it appropriate for polite / formal Japanese or is it a bit slangy? Can I use it in business?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

なにか means "something/anything".

何**を**見つけましたか？ -- "What did you find?"
何**か**見つけましたか？ -- "Did you find something/anything?"

The narration 「何か、見つけました？」 with a rising tone, with the question particle か dropped, can mean "Did he find anything?"
 (「何か見つけました。」 with a falling tone would mean "He found something.")

It is the polite form / 丁寧形 and I don't think it's slangy. I think you can use it in business (though it might be more appropriate to use the honorific form / 尊敬語 depending on who performs the action).

Similar examples:

> 誰**か**いましたか？ (or いました？) -- Was anyone there?
>   誰**が**いましたか？ (or いました？) -- Who was there?
>
> 何**か**食べましたか？ (or 食べました？) -- Did you eat anything?
>   何**を**食べましたか？ (or 食べました？) -- What did you eat?

Comment: Later on in the day I remembered that 何か is "something" and then I wondered if I misunderstood. But with か dropped I was still uncertain.
So with the rising tone I am able to drop か... ok thank you

Comment: Hi! Given that なにか means "something/anything", shouldn't the を particle still be used? In other words, shouldn't it be 何かを見つけましたか instead? Thanks in advance.

Comment: @Hamsteriffic I don't think 何か**を**見つけましたか、誰か**が**いましたか、何か**を**食べましたか etc. are grammatically incorrect, but they don't sound very natural.  何か見つけましたか、誰かいましたか、何か食べましたか are more natural and more commonly used.